# How can I remove all events from the Application Event Log for just one source?

Tags: c#, .net, event-log, eventlog-source

I'm using the application event log to write messages about activity happening in my program. I set the source to the name of my app. I would like to offer the user the ability to clear just the events related to my program. Is this possible? I only see a way to clear the whole log.

I'm using c# in .NET 2.0.

Comment: Did you ever find a different answer?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to clear specific events from an Event log.  It's clear all events or nothing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a piece of code from MSDN library see if this is what your looking for.

```
  string logName;

    if (EventLog.SourceExists("MySource"))
    {
        // Find the log associated with this source.    
        logName = EventLog.LogNameFromSourceName("MySource", ".");
        // Make sure the source is in the log we believe it to be in. 
        if (logName != "MyLog")
            return;
        // Delete the source and the log.
        EventLog.DeleteEventSource("MySource");
        EventLog.Delete(logName);

        Console.WriteLine(logName + " deleted.");
    }
    else
    {
        // Create the event source to make next try successful.
        EventLog.CreateEventSource("MySource", "MyLog");
    }
```

Also what worked for me was creating an Event Source for my application using

```
 if (!EventLog.SourceExists(source))
        {
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(source, additional);
        }
```

and logging all the details in there using

```
 EventLog.WriteEntry(Source, error, EventLogEntryType.Error);
```

and then when i want to clear my logs i use

```
 EventLog myEventLog = new EventLog(Constants.EventSource);
 myEventLog.Clear();
```

This will clear only the logs you've logged under your source. Hope it helps :)